# How to only show the active tab name in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

My WooCommerce product pages displays each product tab seperately and underneath eachother, which is good. The only problem i'm facing is that each tab displays all the tab names. I'd like to only display the name belonging to the tab.

[Example](https://lumenlab.nl/product/menu-jwda-vloerlamp/)

So far, i looked into the tab templates, tried some function snippets. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can hide by css

```
.ec-tabs>li.active, .wc-tabs>li.active {
    display: block;
}
.ec-tabs>li, .wc-tabs>li {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!